# String concatenation in Access VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am trying to write a macro that will create a query based on user input.  The user needs to input a date at the start of the macro and the macro will then incorporate that date into a SQL query.  The problem is I am unsure how to incorporate the date into the SQL `SELECT` statement.  I was thinking of using string concatenation but I am unsure how to do so in the SQL statement.

```
Sub RevH()
Dim dte As String, clientQry As String, db As Database, clientQry1 As Variant


Set db = CurrentDb


dte = InputBox("What date was the Data Dump run?", "Please Input a date")


clientQry = "SELECT DISTINCT " & _
"FN_DataDump_ALL_11032014.[CLIENT ID], " & _
"FN_DataDump_ALL_11032014.[CLIENT NAME] " & _
"FROM " & _
"FN_DataDump_ALL_11032014 " & _
"WHERE (((FN_DataDump_ALL_11032014.[CLIENT NAME]) Not Like  ""*Test*"" ));"

clientQry1 = db.CreateQueryDef("NewIDs", clientQry)
End Sub
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/developingfordynamicsgp/archive/2011/12/16/quick-tip-passing-date-and-time-variables-to-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the question. The `dte` variable will replace the 11032014 in the table name. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be much easier if you use a table alias:

```
dte = InputBox("What date was the Data Dump run?", "Please Input a date (MMDDYYYY)")


clientQry = "SELECT DISTINCT t.[CLIENT ID], t.[CLIENT NAME] " & _
            "FROM FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte & " as t WHERE " & _ 
            " (((t.[CLIENT NAME]) Not Like  ""*Test*"" ));"
```